# 3/4" PEX fittings less than 3/4"?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I have some plumbing that has been done in 3/4" PEX and the 90-degree brass elbow fittings that connect the lengths of tubing fit *inside* the tubing, so I don't see how these elbow fittings could possibly be 3/4" if they are inside 3/4" tubing. The elbows themselves look more like 1/2" pipes to me than 3/4" pipes.

What is the story here? Are PEX fittings smaller diameter than the tubing???

Comment: Ummm - yes, because physics ... It's not clear what sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: The inside of 3/4 pex  tubbing is not 3/4. https://www.pexuniverse.com/pex-tubing-technical-specs

Comment: Because pipe is defined in *trade size*.  The outside diameter of pipe is relevant because that's where fittings attach.   So for instance early 3/4" iron pipe had a 3/4" ID and 1.05" OD by necessity.  Iron pipe fittings go on the outside, so all 3/4" fittings were built for 1.05" OD **and they still are**. Pipe ID changes as materials do. It's like Roman chariots deciding railroad gauge deciding Space Shuttle booster size.

Answer (score 1):

The inside diameter (ID) of PEX fittings is smaller than the ID of the pipe, and the ID of the PEX pipe is smaller than the same size copper pipe.  When the system was designed, the outside diameter was kept constant but the inside diameter shrank (compared to copper).

This sounds like PEX might have much lower flow rates, but the silver lining is that PEX is flexible so it has a lot fewer fittings.  The change in direction in fittings of copper pipe is a flow bottle-neck even if the fittings are larger than the pipe ID.  It's possible to have an entire run of PEX with no fittings at all until it comes out of the wall.

Now, even with that advantage PEX might have a lower flow rate, but it should still be much higher than any point of use calls for outside of a bathtub.  Also, new PEX installs use a manifold system so you don't have 2-3 points of use coming off of one 1/2" line.

Answer (score 1):

I can attest to a significant drop in ID (internal dimension) from PVC to PEX. Just bought materials to graft a PEX relocation to my PVC sprinkler line, which kept being broken from a large pine tree's roots (what developer runs water lines next to a young tree?).

I bought the materials, including 50' of 3/4" PEX a 3/4-to-3/4 PVC threaded converter, and a 3/4-to-3/4 brass thread-to-crimp connector (the best way to connect PVC to PEX underground is to use threaded connectors... the slip-on type won't hold up under ground movement (we live on a slope and the ground is always moving).

I did a test assembly, and was shocked to see the reduced ID on the PEX... it was much more comparable to 1/2" in PVC, and even more of a drop compared to copper. It occurred at the 3/4-to-3/4 brass thread-to-crimp connector... you could see this easily by peering through the assembly.

So I'm moving to 1" PEX for the repair of 3/4" PVC, and using a 3/4-to-1 brass thread-to-crimp connector in order to maintain flow. Water flow is all about maintaining and managing volume, and that cross-sectional ID measurement is the key.

Water flowing through the same nominal dimension of PEX is significantly reduced... it's all about the cross-sectional *area* ... here's a very real example:

The area of a circle is pi times the radius squared (I'll use 3.14 for pi):

3/4" diameter: 3.14 x .375 x .375, or .442" square cross-section

1/2" diameter: 3.14 x .25 x .25, or .196" square cross-section

so even though 1/2" has 67% of the diameter compared to 3/4", it only has 44% of the cross-sectional area, and so also in water volume... less than half.

And if there's ANY connection that reduces the cross-section of the water path, IT CANNOT BE RECOVERED (unlike air). It's like a dam in a river. And to make it worse, friction is greater in a smaller pipe, reducing flow even further. So you can't connect two larger pipes with a smaller pipe and expect the same water flow... the flow will never recover from the smaller section.

So to maintain water volume, you must maintain the internal diameter of your pipes! It's proper that they get smaller as the lines branch out, but not proper to choke it at the source.

Answer (score 0):

There is three main types of PEX tubing: PEXa, PEXb, and PEXc. They differ in the manufacturing process and have their own advantages and disadvantages.

Typically PEXa is expanded over the fitting and as such maintains a larger ID through the fitting. PEXb is not expanded and uses fittings that fit inside the unexpanded tube, and as such have smaller IDs.

I can't speak to PEXc as I've never seen or used it.